# Send email from Outlook Express in C#

Tags: c#

How do I open Outlook Express in C# 2008?

How to attach a file from my application to Outlook?

Comment: Why do you need to use Outlook (or Outlook Express) to send your email?  C# already has built-in support for sending email, using the `System.Net.Mail` namespace.

Comment: @vijaii: your SO bio says you are a "ASP.NET, C#, WPF, SQL server developer", so isn't this something you should be able to work for yourself? Maybe even try a search engine?

Answer (score 8):

Outlook Express has been obsolete for so long I can't even remember the last time I actually *saw* anyone using it... It's a security nightmare, and has been removed from Windows ages ago

AFAIK, Outlook Express doesn't have an API to manipulate it programmatically (but Outlook does). As others have suggested in comments, you should probably send the mail directly from your C# code, without involving Outlook Express. Check out the [`System.Net.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace in MSDN, it contains everything you might need (including code samples)

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out you better use the System.Net.Mail if you simply want to send a mail.

If for whatever reason you want to send mails using Outlook you'll have to use Office interop.
Something like this:

```
 using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                        Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
                        email.Recipients.Add("someEmailAddress@dom.com");
                        email.Subject = "Subject";
                        email.Body = "Message";


                        ((Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to compose an email using the user's default e-mail client, try this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RunMailTo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("mailto://name@example.com");
        }
    }
}
```

You can add additional parameters to the mailto: URL to set the subject, body, etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28VS.85%29.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true. Outlook Express has its own API.

Please look at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710250%28VS.85%29.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/Outlook_Express_Messages.aspx